# Sound problems Cirrus Logic CS4208 Imac 16.1

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, codecs, apple

Hello I've installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 on a Imac 16.1  21.5 A1418 of 2015

1. The sound work bad: the main sound control is actived but the sound
   is not adjustable: It is mute or full. I can adjust by applications
   on gnome-control-center / sound.
2. It run on analog-surround-40 but the fours channel don't go on the
   good speakers.
3. The mic don't work

Some information:

```
imac161@imac161-iMac:~$ grep "Codec:" /proc/asound/card*/codec*
/proc/asound/card0/codec#0:Codec: Intel Broadwell HDMI
/proc/asound/card1/codec#0:Codec: Cirrus Logic CS4208


imac161@imac161-iMac:~$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  1
snd_hda_codec_cirrus    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   122880  1 snd_hda_codec_cirrus
ledtrig_audio          12288  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_intel          61440  7
snd_intel_dspcfg       32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         212992  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hda_core          147456  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               196608  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           24576  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            57344  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq               118784  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              49152  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                   143360  23 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd


imac161@imac161-iMac:~$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-40>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 2620 /   4%,   front-right: 2620 /   4%,   rear-left: 2620 /   4%,   rear-right: 2620 /   4%
            balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100%
volume steps: 128
muted: no
current latency: 17.14 ms
max request: 8 KiB
max rewind: 8 KiB
monitor source: 1
sample spec: s16le 4ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right
         Surround 4.0
used by: 1
linked by: 1
configured latency: 26.00 ms; range is 26.00 .. 2000.00 ms
card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
module: 23
properties:
    alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
    device.api = "alsa"
    device.class = "sound"
    alsa.class = "generic"
    alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
    alsa.name = "CS4208 Analog"
    alsa.id = "CS4208 Analog"
    alsa.subdevice = "0"
    alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
    alsa.device = "0"
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb1614000 irq 75"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "9ca0"
    device.product.name = "Wildcat Point-LP High Definition 
Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "surround40:1"
    device.buffering.buffer_size = "705600"
    device.buffering.fragment_size = "352800"
    device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
    device.profile.name = "analog-surround-40"
    device.profile.description = "Surround analogique 4.0"
    device.description = "Audio interne Surround analogique 4.0"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
ports:
    analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

Comment: Have you tried https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637838/524752 ?

Comment: Yes , I have the same problem with alsa mixer main volume is muted or fully